# Merging two images with PHP

Tags: php, image, merge, resize, overlay

I'm trying to merge two images together with PHP.

For example... how would I go about placing image one on top of image two or merge, with basic PHP?
I have tried something such as watermarking, but it doesn't seem to be working.

**Image One**

[image]

**Image Two**

[image]

...and have it turn into this? **FINAL RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: just display or yu trying to generate the image

Comment: If watermark is working ,but not giving the result as you wanted , my crooked mind is thinking about combination of 3 images. first image is a blank white image, u merge first image onleft side and second image on right side. I know writing code will not be easy as posting comments. Just comment what cam ein my mind

Comment: are you sure you need php? you can easy css it

Comment: I need PHP if I am allowing the users to download the image.

Comment: @Homework You got your answer below. But just for information: You can combine images (and do a lot other stuff too) through JavaScript and the `<canvas>` element. The rendered image can be downloaded by users like you said, too.

Comment: @StanE, thank you for this information. I have learned a lot in the past few years.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I got it working from one I made.

```
<?php
$dest = imagecreatefrompng('vinyl.png');
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('cover2.jpg');

imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);

imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 9, 0, 0, 181, 180, 100); //have to play with these numbers for it to work for you, etc.

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```

Comment: Works on images with transparency.

Answer (score 26):

Question is about merging two images, however in this specified case you shouldn't do that. You should put *Content Image* (ie. cover) into `<img />` tag, and *Style Image* into CSS, why?

1. As I said the cover belongs to the **content** of the document, while that vinyl record and shadow are just a part of the page styles.
2. Such separation is much more convenient to use. User can easily copy that image. It's easier to index by web-spiders.
3. Finally, it's much easier to maintain.

So use a very simple code:

```
<div class="cover">
   <img src="/content/images/covers/movin-mountains.png" alt="Moving mountains by Pneuma" width="100" height="100" />
</div>

.cover {
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 100px;

    background: url(/style/images/cover-background.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I asked for PHP. Still going to save this.

Comment: True. Its easier for the server because it doesnt have to process all images. And its also faster for the user because it doesnt have the part of the image with the vinyl all the time.

Comment: The selected answer is interesting because we can mix two images and share on facebook.

Comment: CSS only works if the images are to be used on a website. Images to be shared on social media, downloaded by users, etc, cannot be created using CSS.

Comment: Could some help me I need to save image after merge. Is this possible by writing html.

Comment: @Crozin how to download image with both background image added from css and the original image as one file.

Answer (score 21):

[ImageArtist](https://github.com/Treinetic/ImageArtist) is a pure gd wrapper authored by me, this enables you to do complex image manipulations insanely easy, for your question solution can be done using very few steps using this powerful library.

here is a sample code.

```
$img1 = new Image("./cover.jpg");
$img2 = new Image("./box.png");
$img2->merge($img1,9,9);
$img2->save("./merged.png",IMAGETYPE_PNG);
```

This is how my result looks like.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.

Comment: Fantastic! you save me hours!

Comment: Perfect +10000 from me :D

Comment: Awesome, was going through the package and noticed the class CircularShape was wondering  if i could add border to the circle shape, or any documentation i could look at?

Answer (score 8):

You can try my function for merging images horizontally or vertically without changing image ratio. just copy paste will work.

```
function merge($filename_x, $filename_y, $filename_result, $mergeType = 0) {

    //$mergeType 0 for horizandal merge 1 for vertical merge

 // Get dimensions for specified images
 list($width_x, $height_x) = getimagesize($filename_x);
 list($width_y, $height_y) = getimagesize($filename_y);


$lowerFileName = strtolower($filename_x); 
if(substr_count($lowerFileName, '.jpg')>0 || substr_count($lowerFileName, '.jpeg')>0){
    $image_x = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename_x);    
}else if(substr_count($lowerFileName, '.png')>0){
    $image_x = imagecreatefrompng($filename_x); 
}else if(substr_count($lowerFileName, '.gif')>0){
    $image_x = imagecreatefromgif($filename_x); 
}


$lowerFileName = strtolower($filename_y); 
if(substr_count($lowerFileName, '.jpg')>0 || substr_count($lowerFileName, '.jpeg')>0){
    $image_y = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename_y);    
}else if(substr_count($lowerFileName, '.png')>0){
    $image_y = imagecreatefrompng($filename_y); 
}else if(substr_count($lowerFileName, '.gif')>0){
    $image_y = imagecreatefromgif($filename_y); 
}


if($mergeType==0){
    //for horizandal merge
     if($height_y<$height_x){
        $new_height = $height_y;

        $new_x_height = $new_height;
        $precentageReduced = ($height_x - $new_height)/($height_x/100);
        $new_x_width = ceil($width_x - (($width_x/100) * $precentageReduced));

         $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($new_x_width, $new_x_height);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image_x, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_x_width, $new_x_height, $width_x, $height_x);
        $image_x = $tmp;

        $height_x = $new_x_height;
        $width_x = $new_x_width;

     }else{
        $new_height = $height_x;

        $new_y_height = $new_height;
        $precentageReduced = ($height_y - $new_height)/($height_y/100);
        $new_y_width = ceil($width_y - (($width_y/100) * $precentageReduced));

         $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($new_y_width, $new_y_height);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image_y, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_y_width, $new_y_height, $width_y, $height_y);
        $image_y = $tmp;

        $height_y = $new_y_height;
        $width_y = $new_y_width;

     }

     $new_width = $width_x + $width_y;

     $image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

    imagecopy($image, $image_x, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_x, $height_x);
    imagecopy($image, $image_y, $width_x, 0, 0, 0, $width_y, $height_y);

}else{


    //for verical merge
    if($width_y<$width_x){
        $new_width = $width_y;

        $new_x_width = $new_width;
        $precentageReduced = ($width_x - $new_width)/($width_x/100);
        $new_x_height = ceil($height_x - (($height_x/100) * $precentageReduced));

        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($new_x_width, $new_x_height);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image_x, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_x_width, $new_x_height, $width_x, $height_x);
        $image_x = $tmp;

        $width_x = $new_x_width;
        $height_x = $new_x_height;

     }else{
        $new_width = $width_x;

        $new_y_width = $new_width;
        $precentageReduced = ($width_y - $new_width)/($width_y/100);
        $new_y_height = ceil($height_y - (($height_y/100) * $precentageReduced));

         $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($new_y_width, $new_y_height);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image_y, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_y_width, $new_y_height, $width_y, $height_y);
        $image_y = $tmp;

        $width_y = $new_y_width;
        $height_y = $new_y_height;

     }

     $new_height = $height_x + $height_y;

     $image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

    imagecopy($image, $image_x, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_x, $height_x);
    imagecopy($image, $image_y, 0, $height_x, 0, 0, $width_y, $height_y);

}





$lowerFileName = strtolower($filename_result); 
if(substr_count($lowerFileName, '.jpg')>0 || substr_count($lowerFileName, '.jpeg')>0){
    imagejpeg($image, $filename_result);
}else if(substr_count($lowerFileName, '.png')>0){
    imagepng($image, $filename_result);
}else if(substr_count($lowerFileName, '.gif')>0){
    imagegif($image, $filename_result); 
}


 // Clean up
 imagedestroy($image);
 imagedestroy($image_x);
 imagedestroy($image_y);

}


merge('images/h_large.jpg', 'images/v_large.jpg', 'images/merged_har.jpg',0); //merge horizontally
merge('images/h_large.jpg', 'images/v_large.jpg', 'images/merged.jpg',1); //merge vertically
```

Comment: Appreciated, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Use the GD library or ImageMagick. I googled 'PHP GD merge images' and got several articles on doing this. In the past what I've done is create a large blank image, and then used imagecopymerge() to paste those images into my original blank one. Check out the articles on google you'll find some source code you can start using right away.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) extension. I'm guessing that the combineImages() method will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

**Merger** two image png and jpg/png **[Image Masking]**

```
//URL or Local path
$src_url = '1.png';
$dest_url = '2.jpg';
$src = imagecreatefrompng($src_url);
$dest1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($dest_url);

//if you want to make same size
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($dest_url);
list($newWidth, $newHeight) = getimagesize($src_url);
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);

imagecopyresampled($dest, $dest1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

list($src_w, $src_h) = getimagesize($src_url);

//merger with same size
$this->imagecopymerge_alpha($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h, 100);

//show output on browser
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagejpeg($dest);
```

[imagecopymerge_alpha](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php)

```
function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct)
    {
        $cut = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h);
        imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h);
        imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);
        imagecopymerge($dst_im, $cut, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h, $pct);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The GD Image Manipulation Library in PHP is probably the best for working with images in PHP. Try one of the imagecopy functions (imagecopy, imagecopymerge, ...). Each of them combine 2 images in different ways. See the [php documentation on imagecopy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) for more information.