# How to make a collage of profile pics from facebook in php?

Tags: php, image-manipulation

I am able to retrieve all of my friend's profile pics.

There are some apps where the some profile pics are stitched together and uploaded into the user's photo album.

I have absolutely no problems retrieving the images or uploading images. I have no idea how to glue together these pics.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging two images with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876299/merging-two-images-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use [`imagecopy()`](http://www.php.net/imagecopy) or even better [`imagecopyresized()`](http://www.php.net/imagecopyresized) and paste them together?

Is this what you were aiming at?

Comment: The links look relevant to what I want to do. I want to create a new image which consists of two smaller images side by side.

Comment: @Karthik check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876299/merging-two-images-with-php is this what you wanted?

Comment: @Karthik Thank you very much for accepting my answer I just wanted to warn you though that this I'm voting to close this question since it is pretty much an exact duplicate! Ok? Glad you found the answer you were looking for!