# Images from Tiles (GD)

Tags: php, gd

I have 4 small JPEG images (40px x 30px) and I want create an image of tiles using GD.

Two at the top and two at the bottom row.

Like this:

```
[][]
[][]
```

How can that be done?

Comment: [`imagecopy()`](http://www.php.net/imagecopy) or [`imagecopyresampled()`](http://php.net/imagecopyresampled) will do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging two images with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876299/merging-two-images-with-php)

Comment: @Trufa similar, but this is splitting an image into tiles, not merging.

Comment: @Jacob nope: "I have 4 small JPEG images...."

Comment: is `imagemagicks`available as well? that might be easier..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions you'll need to use are

- [getimagesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) - Get the width and height so you know what size to make the final image, unless you want to hardcode it.
- [imagecreate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php) - Create resource for the merged image.
- [imagecreatefromjpeg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) - Load the existing tiles as resources.
- [imagecopy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) - Copy the existing tiles into the new image resource, you shouldn't need the resampled function because the size/dimensions aren't changing.
- [imagejpeg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) - Save the merged image.

Here's some untested code that loops through the array of tiles to create it. It uses constants for the width and height.

```
<?php
define('TILE_WIDTH', 40);
define('TILE_HEIGHT', 30);

$tiles = array(
    array('tile1.jpeg', 'tile2.jpeg'),
    array('tile3.jpeg', 'tile4.jpeg'),
);

$saveTo = 'result.jpeg';

$image = imagecreate(TILE_WIDTH * 2, TILE_HEIGHT * 2);
foreach($tiles as $row => $columns) {
    foreach($columns as $col => $filename) {
        $tile = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        imagecopy($image, $tile, $row * TILE_WIDTH, $col * TILE_HEIGHT, 0, 0, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
    }
}

imagejpeg($image, $saveTo);
```

If you want to just display the image, you don't pass the second argument to imagejpeg, but you need to set the header content-type to image/jpeg.

Comment: "Copy a portion of the existing image into a tile".  So how do you add another image into existing title?

Comment: You need to use imagecopy to copy from the tile image resources created with imagecreatefromjpeg into the larger image resource created with imagecreate.