# Get fb profile picture with fb logo on it

Tags: php, facebook

I am  using fb features on my website. I am able to get FB profile pics of the users from facebook. I wanted to have fb logo on these images, its it possible?

Comment: you mean a fb watermark on these profile pics? for this you will need [imagecopy](http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecopy.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Facebook Connect, this page says you can by specific a **facebook-logo** parameter on the tag:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/profile-pic/

Comment: yeah i wanted something like this. But i am using FB graph API. Is there a way to get it using it ?

Answer (score 2):

Just have the fb logo as a png image and use the solution from [Merging two images with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876299/merging-two-images-with-php), to merge the two images. Also Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php)

Answer (score 1):

I would just overlay a Facebook logo using CSS. The graph api doesn't return watermarked photos (which is actually great most of the time).