# Create a Design/Graphic/Artwork Upload form with a mockup preview like Threadless/Overnight prints

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, upload, preview

I'm trying to create a website where users can fill out a form and submit a design (via upload) and show a preview of the uploaded design/image on another image (preview). Basically it'd be like Threadless or Overnightprints.com where the user fills out the form, chooses the color, and uploads the file, then a preview would show the mockup (the uploaded graphic would on the shirt in the color chosen).

I'm not even sure what this is called exactly so if someone can point me to the right direction that would help immensely. Ideally i'd want to do this in wordpress but i'm open to any platforms that will get the job done. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a TODO list for you:

1. [HTML] Create an [upload form](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)
2. [PHP] Process the form (validate and save uploaded data)
3. [PHP] Generate the preview image (image manipulation is done in PHP using fg.[GD library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) - for a quick start see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876299/merging-two-images-with-php))
4. [HTML] Output the preview image

Good luck!