# PHP Merge 3 PNGs into 1 GIF

Tags: php, image, merge, png, gif

I've been searching for an answer to this but found nothing useful:

So I'm trying to design a page whereby a user designs an Icon to use for them self.

They can choose a background, a logo, and a border, from a list of pre-uploaded PNG images. Left and right arrows are used to scroll through the images for each part, the Image number for each part is stored in a Javascript variable for each. (BG=background, FG=foreground icon, BD=border image)

What I need to do is combine the 3 PNGs into a single GIF image, which needs to be saved in a certain location.  Is this possible? From what I've read online it is possible to merge them together, but I would have no idea where to start with it, or how to do it.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow (SO). There are many similar questions to your, one possible duplicate is [Merging two images with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876299/merging-two-images-with-php). I suggest you use the search and look around a bit before asking a question, you might already find what you're looking for. Also a nice library is [wideimage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/) for jobs like the one you describe in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install and use GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick from php. There are many good tutorials and the documentation is great. GD Lib can do it, but the others are typically faster and (in my experience) do a better job.