# Combine 2 or more pictures in PHP

Tags: php, image

Imagine I have 2 pictures, imagea.jpg and imageb.jpg

[image: ImageA]

Image A

[image: ImageB]

Image B

I want to combine these both pictures un just 1 and output them to a file imageab.jpg, just like here

[image: ImageA]
[image: ImageB]

I will do this running cron jobs, so I need to do that on PHP, but I'm getting troubles with previous codes. As additional information, I'm getting the ImageA/B URLs from MySQL and all pictures have the same width and height.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341967/merge-pictures-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagick is your friend.

For example [Imagick::appendImages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.appendimages.php).

Comment: This is the correct answer, but how can I make it, can you edit with the code? Thanks!

Comment: What code would you need, everything you need to know is in the manual?

Comment: Yes, but they are doing images from colors, I want to know how to do the same but with previously done images (image url). Thanks!

Comment: Exactly the same but instead you load the images first with Imagick::readImage.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [imagecopymerge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php):

Something like this:

```
$dest = imagecreatefromgjpg('imagea.jpg');
$src = imagecreatefromjpg('imageb.jpg');

// Copy and merge
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 10, 0, 0, 100, 47, 75);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

imagejpeg($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at GD and imagemagick, they are plenty of functions that can help you:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php