# Save multiple absolute images as one

Tags: php, jquery

On my site i have some images which can be dragged around

```
 draggable()
```

Because it's draggable the images are absolute.

The images are all in one div 800 x 400 px .

What i want to do is get all images in the div and convert it to 1 picture.

So from example 20 pictures above each other (different z-indexes) I want to make 1 picture.

I got an example of user created image (wich is diffrent images dragged ) http://ve.svenboogaart.nl/test/moodboards.php?id=46 the images are always in the 800 x 400 px div .

It needs to be saved as picture so users can save it as a picture !

Comment: This question is relevant - though you clearly will want to do it on a larger scale. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876299/merging-two-images-with-php

Comment: maybe you can use canvas instead of div, than you can create an img from your canvas like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly :

1. You have a 800x400 image with 20 sprites (20 x 160x100 images)
2. You have 20 absolute positionned elements, which are draggable
3. You want to display the images in each element

Is that it?

If so, you simply need CSS to offset your background image. For example:

#### CSS

```
.big-image-container { position: relative; }
.big-image { background-image: url(path/to/your/image); background-repeat:no-repeat; }
.draggable-sprite { position:absolute; width: 160px; height: 100px; }
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="container" class="big-image-container">
</div>
```

#### JS

```
var spriteCountX = 5;
var spriteCountY = 4;
var container = $("#container");
var sprite, bgx, bgy;
for (var x=0; x<spriteCountX; x++) {
   for (var y=0; y<spriteCountY; y++) {
       sprite = $("<div>").addClass("big-image draggable-sprite")
          .appendTo(container);

       bgx = x * sprite.width();
       bgy = y * sprite.height();
       sprite.css("background-position", bgx + "px " + bgy + "px");
   }
}
```

What this does is simply offset the big image inside each draggable elements so they seem to have different images as background. Many JavaScript libraries uses this trick for their icon set (see [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) for example.)

** **Update** **

To convert the draggable images into a big image that users can download, you'll need to collect the position, sizes and background images of each draggable elements and construct them server side. For example

#### JS

```
function renderCanvas() {
    var imageInfo = [];
    $( <draggableElementsSelector> ).each(function(i, e) {
        imageInfo.push({
            position: $(e).position(),  // -> { top, left }
            dimension: { width: $(e).width(), height: $(e).height() },
            imageClass: $(e).attr("class")  // .. what you need to get the bg img
        });
    });

    $.post("url/to/script", { images: imageInfo })
       .done(function(response) { 

            // response.imageSrc should be a link to your image for download

       })
       .fail(function() { alert("Image creation failed"); });
}
```

#### PHP

```
$imageInfo = $_POST['images'];
$imgWidth = 1; // min, just in case, cannot be 0
$imgHeight = 1; // min, just in case, cannot be 0

// first pass to find the dest image size
foreach ($imageInfo as $img) {
    $imgWidth = max($imgWidth, $img->position->left + $img->dimension->width);
    $imgHeight = max($imgHeight, $img->position->top + $img->dimension->height);
}

$destImage = imagecreate($imgWidth, $imgHeight); // (x, y)

foreach ($imageInfo as $img) {
   $src = imagecreatefrompng( getImagePath($img->imageClass) );

   imagecopymerge($destImage, $src, 
       $img->position->left, $img->position->top,
       0, 0, $img->dimension->width, $img->dimension->height);
}

$imgFilename = generateImageFile( ... );  // whatever you need here

// Save the image to file.png 
imagepng($destImage, $imgFilename);


$imgLink = convertFileToUrl( $imgFilename );   // generate downloadable link

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('imageSrc' => $imgLink));
exit();   // end here
```

Comment: nope, i need it to be converted to a image (jpg png dosnt matter) It all looks good on the site but i need an image so users can share it.

Comment: I see. Then I'll update my answer.