# how can I put image on image and resize and drag it

Tags: php, jquery, css

I want to implement  customize mug design with PHP,
by default there is  glass image is there, then user can upload her/his image , the the image will put on the glass, user change resize and move it, like below picture

[image]

how can I implement it , any idea? any help about some jquery libraries ....

Comment: You can use draggable() and resizable() from jQueryUI. There is a lot of options like constraint on a container (your red rectangle for exemple)

Comment: There are some plugins already available for that, e.g: http://codecanyon.net/item/tshirt-designer/full_screen_preview/5714484?ref=jqueryrain Which is not free but as i'm not related to them, so i post link here. I guess you could find other ones using google

Comment: @ShailParas I dont try anything yet, I want study first then keep on

Comment: @A.Wolff that is great, but I dont want wordpress plugin, my base is drupal. do you know any raw php jquery method?

Comment: @zhilevan, did you read my comment ? You can do all that what you want with this: http://jsfiddle.net/mYL2t/

Comment: drag ui plugin jquery =)
You are welcome

Comment: @Superdrac yes I read, tnx  for you solution, but finally how can I save it?

Comment: Do you want all the app code ?

Comment: @Superdrac How is he has `720 repetition with 10 silver badge and 30 bronze badges`. He is asking full app code from you? -_-

Comment: I didn't say that, he ask for solution to resize & drag image on a model, we give it, and he ask how to save it ? It's not his job to think about "how to save it" ?

Comment: @Superdrac thank you, but can you tell me how can I put this this movable object on another image and merge them?

Comment: Search on stack, lot of subjects about images merging with differents technologies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876299/merging-two-images-with-php

Comment: @Superdrac thank you very much, can you merge your answers in one and post it as answer please, maybe it will be others problem and you complete answer help them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For image dragging & resizing, you can use the [.draggable()](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) & [.resizable()](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/) functions in jQuery UI.

This is fully customized and you will be able to reach your goal easily.

For image merging, you can use the code from this [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876299/merging-two-images-with-php):

```
<?php
    $dest = imagecreatefrompng('vinyl.png');
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg('cover2.jpg');

    imagealphablending($dest, false);
    imagesavealpha($dest, true);

    imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 9, 0, 0, 181, 180, 100); //have to play with these numbers for it to work for you, etc.

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($dest);

    imagedestroy($dest);
    imagedestroy($src);
```

?>

And if you use PHP, also have a look to [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) for All your need , It uses canvas under the hood

- there you can set your image on cup
- resize it , drag it
- and save image in dataurl then to any jpeg or png