# How to merge images in PHP?

Tags: php, css, image

I have two images which are loaded from an external URL. I want to place one image on top of another (keeping the size). I actually don't know the sizes of the images as they are from an external URL and are different each time.

So I want a function which can be called like `merge($url1,$url2,$final_name)`. I have googled on this but none worked.

I want this `3.png` :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                          |
                              IMAGE 1                                     |
                                                                          |
                                                                          |
___________________________________________________________________________

                                                                          |
                              IMAGE 2                                     |
                                                                          |
                                                                          |
___________________________________________________________________________
```

```
$top_file = 'image1.png';
$bottom_file = 'image2.png';

$top = imagecreatefrompng($top_file);
$bottom = imagecreatefrompng($bottom_file);

// get current width/height
list($top_width, $top_height) = getimagesize($top_file);
list($bottom_width, $bottom_height) = getimagesize($bottom_file);

// compute new width/height
$new_width = ($top_width > $bottom_width) ? $top_width : $bottom_width;
$new_height = $top_height + $bottom_height;

// create new image and merge
$new = imagecreate($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopy($new, $top, 0, 0, 0, 0, $top_width, $top_height);
imagecopy($new, $bottom, 0, $top_height+1, 0, 0, $bottom_width, $bottom_height);

// save to file
imagepng($new, 'merged_image.png');
```

This does the job but the merged image loses its color and becomes nearly black and white like this:

[image]

Comment: Why is this even tagged javascript if it's just php?

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal i want to use java script to write this `document.write("Hello World")` , just because i added this tag!

Comment: Just to sum up again. Do you want to load 2 images from an external url and combine them to one big image, right?

Comment: @Andi Yes. i want to do exactly this

Comment: Maybe take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876299/merging-two-images-with-php

Comment: @Andi Thats for merging images on top of each other not below each other!

Comment: @Andi Can you fix my function?

Comment: try this for both $top and $bot:
$top = imagecreatefrompng($top_file);
imageAlphaBlending($top, true);
imageSaveAlpha($top, true);

maybe you'll have to do this for $new instead

Comment: @Andi I added it for both but still the same resukt

Comment: @Andi can you edit and add image to my answer please

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
// create new image and merge
$new = imagecreate($new_width, $new_height);
```

I used:

```
// create new image and merge
$new = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
```

It worked!

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i looked up ur code but i would save the folder in something like that:

```
$time = date('d-M-Y') . '-TIME-' . date('H-i-s');    
$save_finalimage_socialmedia = public_path("storage/image-{$time}.jpeg");
        imagejpeg($new, $save_finalimage_socialmedia);
```

PS: i did it in the jpeg format, so if you want, you can change in ur format (png,jpg,...)
PS: @user4273356 ur code worked for me